# Avoid shaking of background when resizing div

Tags: css

I'm trying to expand a div from the center with an image as a background. The problem is that the background shakes a bit during the transition. Is there anything that could be done to avoid that? or any other solution?

Click on "iniciar" to see it. https://jsbin.com/puqaran

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div>
      <div class="slide_wrapper">  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (just for testing purposes, div insertion)

```
var slider = $('#slider');
var slides = [
     "https://i.imgur.com/VekWaBu.jpg",
    "https://i.imgur.com/IFeSs4m.jpg",
    "https://i.imgur.com/hhqWERQ.jpg",
    "https://i.imgur.com/7eT5TOE.jpg",
    "https://i.imgur.com/oQgYW16.jpg"
  ];


function addSlide() { 
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 0;
    slider.find('.slide_wrapper').children().remove();
    slider.find('.slide_wrapper').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url('+ slides[rand] +')"></div>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      slider.find('.slide_wrapper').children().last().addClass('slide-extend');
    }, 1);
}
```

CSS

```
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Jl24Wuy.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
#slider > div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide_wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px; 
  border: 1px solid #f00; 
  transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
  background-position: center center; 
}
.slide.slide-extend {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I've tried a couple of html markups and css combinations with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't notice any shaking. What web browser are you using to notice this?

Comment: @IvanSanchez have you pressed the iniciar button?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Google Chrome on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6. Press the button and you will see some shaking.